# Ignoring effect of non-significant labels in PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I had a prometheus metric upload_latency with single label device_id. In prometheus web UI, with query of 'upload_latency' i see different lines for each device_id.

Now to enhance debugging i have added another label msg_type. If i query 'upload_latency' now, it plots separate lines for each combination of device_id and msg_type. It helps when i want to visualize latency w.r.t. msg_type but not when i really just want to visualize collective latencies per device_id.

What i am looking for is a way to ignore the label msg_type so that i can plot the lines per device_id like earlier whenever needed.

Any comments appriciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using an aggregation combined with `without`.

Something like `sum without (msg_type) upload_latency`

Whether you use sum or max or some other aggregator function depends on if data points with the same device id and different message type can happen at the same time or not. But either way, `without` should be helpful.

Link to the relevant documentation:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. I used 'avg without (msg_type) (upload_latency)' and it is working as expected. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: How do you ignore a label without aggregating? I want to get a histogram_quantile without a label, but apparently that's impossible in prom because you can't discard labels without aggregating?

Answer (score 0):

If non-essential labels aren't known in advance, while all the essential labels are known in advance, then it is better to use `avg(...) by (essential_labels)` instead of `avg(...) without (non_essential_labels)`. For example, the following query returns the average upload latency per each `device_id` and this doesn't depend on the number of additional non-essential labels in `upload_latency` time series:

```
avg(upload_latency) by (device_id)
```

See [docs about aggregate functions in PromQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions) and [docs about avg()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg).

Additional notes: non-essential labels can be removed from time series during querying with [label_keep](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_keep) and [label_del](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_del) functions when using Prometheus-compatible query engine such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/).